# Android ConstraintLayout Problem inside CardView

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I Have problem on `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` inside `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`

Basically I want to nested ConstraintLayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
       <TextView/>
       <Spinner/>
       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
         </EditText>
       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then, I don't know why, the second `ConstraintLayout` child doesn't appears. Please take a look preview design below.

[image]

Here are complete code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FindTourFragment" android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
            android:id="@+id/job_list_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/job_list_toolbar">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Lokasi"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    style="@style/InputLabel"

                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"/>

            <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"

                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView"/>


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"

                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

                <EditText
                        android:hint="Tanggal Keberangkatan"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="date"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/editText2"
                        android:clickable="true"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/listview"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Ps. I have also try on Emulator, same result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `TextView` inside your inner `ConstraintLayout` has this attribute:

> ```
> app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
> ```

This is positioning your TextView to be outside the bounds of the ConstraintLayout. Since everything else is constrained to this view, everything else is also outside the bounds of the ConstraintLayout.

Change it to be constrained to the **top** of the parent instead:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```